# In react native, how to customize alert text array using FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

In react native, how to customize alert text array using FlatList.

In case first item click, I wanna show 'Alert First' of Alert Title.

But it is hard to sync id between ALERT_TITLE and props{id}.

After fail many times, I require stack overflow.

please answer of my question.

Below my code and reference from https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/flatlist

I'm not sure const array set
const ALERT_TITLE = {'Alert First', 'Alert Second', 'Alert Third'};
or
const ALERT_TITLE = [{id: 'aa', title: 'Alert First ',},{id: 'bb', title: 'Alert Second ',},{id: 'cc', title: 'Alert Third ',},];

```
const ALERT_TITLE = [
  {id: 'aa', title: 'Alert First ',},
  {id: 'bb', title: 'Alert Second ',},
  {id: 'cc', title: 'Alert Third ',},
];
const ALERT_MESSAGE = [
  {id: 'aa', title: 'msg First ',},
  {id: 'bb', title: 'msg Second ',},
  {id: 'cc', title: 'msg Third ',},
];

const DATA = [
  {id: 'aa', title: 'First Item',},
  {id: 'bb', title: 'Second Item',},
  {id: 'cc', title: 'Third Item',},
];

function Item({ id, title, selected, onSelect }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => Alert.alert(
        ALERT_TITLE.toDoSomeThing,//{if first item click I wanna show 'Alert First'}
        ALERT_MESSAGE.toDoSomeThing,//{if first item click I wanna show 'msg First'}
        [
          { text: 'Cancel'},
          { text: 'OK', onPress: () => onSelect(id)}
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      )}

      style={[
        styles.item,
        { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(new Map());

  const onSelect = React.useCallback(
    id => {
      const newSelected = new Map(selected);
      newSelected.set(id, !selected.get(id));

      setSelected(newSelected);
    },
    [selected],
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Item
            id={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            selected={!!selected.get(item.id)}
            onSelect={onSelect}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        extraData={selected}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ALERT_MESSAGE and ALERT_TITLE are arrays, so they doesn't provide the ALERT_TITLE.toDoSomeThing or ALERT_MESSAGE.toDoSomeThing acessors.

To display the desired text, you should find the desired item on the ALERT_TITLE and ALERT_MESSAGE arrays, and access the fields from them, like this

```
function Item({ id, title, selected, onSelect }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => Alert.alert(
        ALERT_TITLE.find(el => el.id === id).title,//{if first item click I wanna show 'Alert First'}
        ALERT_MESSAGE.find(el => el.id === id).title,//{if first item click I wanna show 'msg First'}
        [
          { text: 'Cancel'},
          { text: 'OK', onPress: () => onSelect(id)}
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      )}

      style={[
        styles.item,
        { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  );
}
```

Another way (that is faster than this one) is to pass the index of the item to the Item component, like this:

Your flatlist declaration become:

```
<FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
      <Item
        id={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        selected={!!selected.get(item.id)}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        index={index}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    extraData={selected}
    />
```

and your Item component grab the index via props

```
function Item({ id, title, selected, onSelect, index }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => Alert.alert(
        ALERT_TITLE[index].title,//{if first item click I wanna show 'Alert First'}
        ALERT_MESSAGE[index].title,//{if first item click I wanna show 'msg First'}
        [
          { text: 'Cancel'},
          { text: 'OK', onPress: () => onSelect(id)}
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      )}

      style={[
        styles.item,
        { backgroundColor: selected ? '#6e3b6e' : '#f9c2ff' },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  );
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it was the correct answer, mark it as correct so the next person that faces this issues can be more confident about the solution